# Команда zip для windows 10 с интерфейсом cmd

Tags: python, windows-10

На днях понадобилась возможность использования команды архивации zip в cmd windows 10. Так как по дефолту такой команды нет, я узнал что она устанавливается из GnuWin32, есть два способа установки(архив и установщик- скачал через последний)не понимая что делать дальше просто установил как прогу, хотя думаю что надо что то делать с переменной средой PATH. Может вопрос глупый но буду благодарен, также если с вдруг этим все туго то может есть другие способы или команды о которых я не знаю)

Comment: В чем вопрос? Какая проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вам использовать команду `rar` из WinRar.
Чтобы она работала в любом месте, откуда вы её вызовите - нужно добавить её в переменную PATH.

Для этого:

1. Панель управления -> Система -> Дополнительные параметры системы ->
   переменные среды
2. Выбираете системные переменные и там PATH
3. Нажимаете *изменить* -> *создать* -> пишете туда путь до папки, где
   установлен WinRar. У меня, например, это `C:\Program Files\WinRAR`

[image: PATH]

Теперь сохраняете, и можно вызвать консоль, написать `rar help` и почитать про использование команды ([или здесь почитать](https://winrar-fansite.com/instructions/konsolnye-komandy-winrar-primery.html))

Из Python вызывается просто:

```
import os
os.system("rar     режим работы (например a - добавить в архив)     название архива  
  путь до папки/файла который нужно добавить")
```

Например:

```
import os
os.system("cd C:\\ && rar a folder.zip C:\\folder")
```

Но обратите внимание: для создания файлов на диске **C** нужны права администратора. Эта команда выполнилась успешно, потому что я запустил Python от имени администратора.