# Нету файла zip.exe в GnuWin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

Операционная система - Windows 10

---

При запуске кода из книги у меня высвечивалась вот эта ошибка

```
'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

В попытке решить эту проблему мне подсказали скопировать путь к папке zip.exe 
Но проблема в том, что этого файла у меня просто нету 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовала скачивать приложение заново, но этого файла так и нигде небыло 
PS:
При запуске этого кода возникла ошибка, которую я пытаюсь решить

```
import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['C:\\My Documents', ' ' ,   'C:\\Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'C:\\Backup' # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете использовать.

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = 'zip -qr {0} {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))
# Запускаем создание резервной копии
print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
   print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
   print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Зайдя в папку 7-zip тоже не нашла файл zip_exe:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: При посике zip_exe вот что выдало. Как я понимаю это не то что нужно?]

Comment: `Win + PauseBreak` -> Дополнительные параметры -> Переменные среды -> Системные переменные -> `PATH` -> добавить (именно добавить, а **не стереть все и написать новое**) в него путь до файла, который исполняет данную команду. Он называется `zip.exe`, находится там, где вы установили архиватор. Вот [вариант с картинками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134232/384202), там для команды `rar`, но принцип тот же.

Comment: `проблема в том, что этого файла у меня просто нету` вы установили 7-zip?

Comment: @Стас Проблема в том что я просмотрела все папки в GnuWin32 но не нашла файл zip.exe. Зайдя на ссылку которую вы мне скинули, я сделала все что мне было сказано. Но получила эту ошибку:''rar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Comment: Он не должен находиться в `GnuWin32` (если вы его туда не установили). При установке вы выбрали папку, где он должен находиться (по умолчанию `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` или `C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip`). Если вы выбирали другую - отправьтесь туда и найдите файл. Или просто воспользуйтесь поиском

Comment: @Стас Я устанавлива 7-zip . Но зайдя в эту папку тоже ничего не нашла. В папке которая была первая тоже не было этого файла. Скриншот я прикрепила сверху

Comment: И если он всё равно не нашёлся - переустановите и выберите папку, где вы его потом найдёте

Comment: Переустановить 7-zip?

Comment: Ваш исполняемый файл называется `7z` - добавьте путь до него, и используйте команду `7z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Команда `zip` используется в Linux командой:

```
zip -r {filename.zip} {foldername}
```

В Windows вы можете использовать 7zip. В таком случае нужно добавить в переменную PATH путь до папки, где установлен 7zip. Он находится по умолчанию в `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` или `C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip`. После этого можно использовать

```
7z a -tzip {имя_файла.zip} {папка}
```

Подробнее о том, как изменить значение переменной PATH:

Для этого:

1. `Win + PauseBreak` -> Дополнительные параметры системы ->
   переменные среды
2. Выбираете системные переменные и там PATH
3. Нажимаете *изменить* -> *создать* -> пишете туда путь до папки, где
   установлен 7zip.

[image: PATH]

Comment: Имя файла - указать путь к фалу который я хочу скопировать, а папка - это путь, куда я хочу скопировать. Верно?

Comment: @ВикторияМолотова `{имя_файла.zip}` это путь и имя до будущего архива, `{foldername}` - папка, которая должна быть заархивирована. [Подробнее здесь](https://7-zip.org.ua/ru/help/)

Comment: Сегодня у меня уже болит голова. Завтра опробую ваш ответ и отпишусь, помогло или нет

Comment: @ Спасибо, помогли)